# How to use get object in controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, laravel-5

I have a function in controller to remove category and its image file. But i am not able to access the path property. I am getting this error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$path. It is returning path but i am unable to use it.

```
public function remove($id) {
    //$category = Category::find($id)->delete();

    $category_image = CategoryImage::where('category_id', '=', $id)->get(['path']);

    echo $category_image->path;


    //return back();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-first) if you need to get just one object:

```
$category_image = CategoryImage::where('category_id', '=', $id)->first();

if (!is_null($category_image)) { // Always check if object exists.
    echo $category_image->path;
}
```

When you're using `get()`, you're getting a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections). In this case you can iterate over the collection and get data from each object, or just use index:

```
$category_image[0]->path;
```

Comment: You could also do this with the if statement if you didn't want to be as verbose 

    if ($category_image) {
        echo $category_image->path;
    }

Answer (score 1):

You get a collection, you have to loop throug the collection this way:

```
foreach ($category_image as $image) {
echo $image->path;
```

}